# pull the new name of the excel file but not sure how. any ideas?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I pull an excel file then copy that file and renew the new file but not sure how to edit that new excel file that I renamed in the code. how to pull the new name when you don't know the new name until you renew the copy new excel file?

```py
import os.path
import shutil
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.now().strftime("%m_%d_%y")
file_exists = os.path.exists('blacklisting_'+ date +'.xlsx')
blacklist = os.path.exists("blacklist_list.txt")

if not file_exists:
    shutil.copyfile("blacklisting_template.xlsx", 'blacklisting_template - copy.xlsx')
    os.rename('blacklisting_template - Copy.xlsx', 'blacklisting_' + date + '.xlsx')
    print(f'this file exists now.')
if file_exists:
    print("this file is real")
```

Comment: Not enough info

Comment: i edit it. i hope that is better

Comment: Not entirely sure I'm following. Is the problem you dont know the name of the excel file you just copied? When you copy a file you provide the name, so if you store that name in a variable then you can use that going forward.

Comment: Before renaming file in code 'blacklisting_' + date + '.xlsx' , create a variable  as new_file_name = 'blacklisting_' + date and try to use for future reference in code.

Comment: something like this
```new_excelfile = ('blacklisting_' + date + '.xlsx')
print(new_excelfile)```